# Creating Julia sets using Python

Tags: dynamical-systems, fractals, python, programming

I want to create my own images of the Julia set of the complex function $e^z-2$, similar to the one below:

[image]

The simple (Python) program:

```
import cmath
from PIL import Image 

if __name__ == "__main__": 

w, h, zoom = 1600,1000,1

bitmap = Image.new("RGB", (w, h), "white") 

pix = bitmap.load() 

maxIter = 6

for x in range(w): 
    for y in range(h): 
        zx = 1.0*(x - w/2)/200 + 3 
        zy = 1.0*(y - h/2)/200 + 0
        z=complex(zx,zy)
        i = maxIter 
        while  z.real< 50 and i > 1:
            z=cmath.exp(z)-complex(2,0)
            i -= 1
        if i==1:
            pix[x,y] = 255,255,255
        if i>1:
            pix[x,y] = 0,0,0

bitmap.show()
```

produces this image:

[image]

Essentially, the Julia set of this function is just the set of escaping points.  So the idea for my program was to test the first few iterates of the function on each point $z$, and see if any of those iterates is large (in modulus or just the real part). But clearly it's not good enough.  How can I improve it to get the top image? Or, can you give a new Python code to produce the top image?

Comment: one way to start would be to switch to greyscale. Instead of a pixel being on / off, set the color to be proportional to the speed at which it escapes. I.e., if you exit the while loop when i is still large, make it nearly white; if i is only 2 or 3 when the loop exits, make it nearly black. You should start to see more structure emerge.

Comment: You'll almost certainly need more iterations to get at those fine details, too. And you can speed up the whole process by using numpy.array() and eliminating both for loops.

Comment: Looking at the [wikipedia image resembling your first picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Exp-esc.png), the iterations used there is different, $z_{+1}=(e^z-1)/2$. And indeed that iteration gives about that form, if you increase `MaxIter` enough. Also look at [codereview for Julia computations with numpy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144193/generating-julia-set-fractal?rq=1) on how to substantially speed up the computation. You can also research on how you can use the `Image.putdata` function to make writing the image faster.

Comment: The correct codereview link that I wanted to cite is this one with an [answer on simultaneous iterations in Mandelbrot computation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/161536/168605), using index masks to tell the faster numpy operations where the calculations have to happen.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your black pixels represent points which do not escape, where "escape" is characterized in your program by having a real part exceeding 50 by the 6th iteration.

If you want more points to qualify as escapees, you can either (1) increase the number (now 6) of iterations, or (2) decrease the minimum real part (now 50) required to decide an iterate has escaped.

It may possibly help efficiency to combine two iterations in a single computation (but I'm not sure if that's true).

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think i=1 is actually producing a white pixel.  I would like to start by removing (refining) the black "blob" on the right, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

On first look, your code looks ok. I've experimented with Cantor Bouquets alot, (that's what these Julias ar called) and found that the bailout value needs to be really high to clear the internal regions and push the solid boundary back. Think in the range of $10^{50}$ to $10^{80}$ for some really solid resolution. I don't know if Python can handle such large numbers. I used Maple and the results are satisfying. Note that if you use too high a number of iterations, you'll lose threads as well. The balance seems to be around 100-200 iterations with a bailout of round the range I gave above. Good luck.

Comment: right, it appears Python cannot handle those numbers. I can't even increase the bound to 1000 or it gives me: OverflowError: math range error.

Comment: Do you still have your Maple program?  I just downloaded Maple but cannot program in the language...

Comment: I don't have the code available but you can download it from this page: [link]https://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/200721-Tetrational-Code-Viewer-Vs-101[\link]. It's the Euler.mw document. The prodedure of interest is J.